# How to go to last change not made on the current screen?

Tags: cursor-movement

I love `g;`, but often I find myself repeatedly doing `g;` until the screen changes. The reason for this is that I am often editing in two different places in the file. If I think ahead, I should set marks at the two places, but I usually forget to do this. Also, I don't know how many edits I made at the current "screen" so I can't just do `ng;` for some n. An alternative workflow would be to split the screen and edit in two places that way, but I just haven't gotten used to that workflow and even in that case, I think I would still find this functionality useful. Finally, I often use `''` but it often doesn't do what I want since I commonly search different parts of the file and I really want to jump to the last part of the file (that's not on the current screen) where I made a change.

How can I make a command that will essentially repeat `g;` until the screen changes?

Comment: You could try C-o instead, though it navigates differently than g;

Comment: C-o is indeed nice! But I think it navigates through the jumplist where I want to navigate through the changelist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward

```
nnoremap <expr>g; DeltaChange()

func! DeltaChange() abort
  let ch = getchangelist()
  let delta = 1
  let top = line('w0')
  let bot = line('w$')
  while delta <= ch[1]
    let lnum = ch[0][ch[1] - delta].lnum
    if lnum < top || lnum > bot
      return delta..'g;'
    endif
    let delta += 1
  endw
  return ''
endf
```